# enabling MySQL v5.6.27 general query log

Tags: mysql

I want to enable the general query log for MySQL v5.6.27 on ubuntu.

file I edit is located at:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

I have tried inputting the following to the my.cnf file:

```
general_log=1
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

I then try to restart the MySQL server and the terminal just hangs.

The file permissions for the query log are as follows:

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 mysql mysql     0 Nov 24 13:28 mysql.log
```

If I remove the lines then the MySQL server restarts fine.
So the above lines do not belong in that file.

Any ideas where I am going wrong with this one ?

Thanks in advance

Ad

Comment: mysql user most likely does not have write permission on `query.log`

Comment: did you try to give 777 temporarily to your /log/mysql path. Just try, if not woks change permission to its default values so you can be sure about permissions.

`chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql/` then
`chmod 777 /var/log/mysql/`

Comment: have tried , still no joy :-/ .I think its a syntactical error as the server hangs when I try to restart it. If I remove the lines from my.cnf the server restarts fine.

Comment: did you try `SET global general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/query.log` on mysql command line on your shell

Comment: /var/log/mysql/mysql.log do you really have this path and file on your server? did you check it manually? IF you did not CREATE your log file you  must create it. MYSQL can not create it.

Comment: read this article carefully http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-and-when-to-enable-mysql-logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the reason was that the 2 lines that are required in my.cnf

```
general_log=1
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

simply needs this putting above it:

```
[mysqld]
general_log=1
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

This then resolved the restarting issue and the logs working when I tail them.

Thanks [@hakkikonu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848929/hakkikonu) for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

try 'ON' instead of '1' `general_log = 'ON';`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html

also if your file path for your log file not writable for mysql you cannot do anything. Give permission to mysql for write.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8788032/1848929

Comment: I have added the current file permission to the description.

Comment: I have tried changing '1' to 'ON' and still hangs when I restart the server.